# How to match only particular events with Python watchdog

Tags: python

I'm intending to use Python watchdog to handle a directory where files are written to, 
and I'm only interested in image files, trouble is I dont quite grok the code at [this page](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html). 
This is my attempt:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class Beat(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
     def on_create(self,event):
             print event.src_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patt = ['\w+[.]jpeg']
    event_handler = Beat(patterns=patt,ignore_directories=True,) 
    observer = Observer()
    path = "./"
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
```

I'm trying to use the pattern matching class, but I'm getting nothing. How is it supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/pathtools/blob/master/pathtools/patterns.py), [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) is being used under the hood. `fnmatch` can only do UNIX glob-style pattern matching. Which means you may have better luck with `*.jpg` than `\w+[.]jpeg`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the RegexMatchingEventHandler instead of PatternMatchingEventHandler to accomplish exactly what you want to do:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler  

class ExampleHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):
     def on_create(self, event):
             print(event.src_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pattern = '\w+\.jpeg'
    event_handler = ExampleHandler(regexes=[pattern], ignore_directories=True) 
    observer = Observer()
    path = "./"
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    import time
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```